# Quarkus Mutiny: Multy to Uni Returns null

Tags: quarkus, reactive, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

I have a reactive program and i am adding to an Arraylist  employees, as long as there isn't an employee with the same id following the code bellow.The thing is that it returns null even though the Arraylist has no employees in, So there can't be one with the same.

```java
public Uni<Employee> addEmployeee(Employee employee){
        return Multi.createFrom().iterable(employees)
                .onItem().transform(empl -> {
                    if(empl.getId().equals(employee.getId())){
                        return null;
                    }else {
                        employees.add(employee) ;
                    }
                    return employee ;
                }).toUni() ;
    }
```

I have achieved that with the following code but i think the previous code is better.

```java
public Uni<Employee> addEmployee(Employee employeeToAdd){
       return Uni.createFrom().item(employees)
                .onItem().transform(employees ->{
                    Optional<Employee> exists = employees.stream().filter(empl ->  empl.getId().equals(employeeToAdd.getId())).findFirst();
                    if(exists.isEmpty()){
                        employees.add(employeeToAdd);
                        return employeeToAdd;
                    }
                    return null;
                });
    }
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: You cannot emit `null` in a Multi; this is not legal (this is constrained by the reactive streams specification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code with `Multi` should be:

```
public Uni<Employee> addEmployeee(Employee employee){
    return Multi.createFrom()
                .iterable( employees )
                .filter( entry -> entry.getId().equals( employee.getId() ) )
                .collect()
                .first()
                .map( found -> {
                    if ( found == null ) {
                        // Not in the list
                        employees.add( employee );
                        return employee;
                    }
                    // Already in the list
                    return null;
                } );
}
```

The original solution doesn't work because you are applying the same code for each entry of the `employees` collection

But I don't know if I would use a Multi in this case, it seems like you can rewrite the code as:

```
private boolean contains(Employee employee) {
    for (Employee e : employees) {
        if ( e.getId().equals( employee.getId() ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public Uni<Employee> addEmployee(Employee employeeToAdd){
    if ( contains( employeeToAdd ) ) {
       return Uni.createFrom().nullItem();
    }
    employess.add(employeeToAdd);
    return Uni.createFrom().item(employeeToAdd);
}
```

That looks simpler.

Also, if `Employee` implements `Comparable`, you can just use `employees.contains(employeeToAdd)`.